# kill the associated buffer when close the emacs-client frame by pressing Alt+F4

Tags: emacs

I get used to emacsclient for the speedy response like vim, by putting emacs into sever mode with command "emacs --daemon". But I found it quite annoying that lots of buffers kept alive when I viewed some files and then closed them by pressing Alt+F4. I have to kill the buffer explicitly before closing the frame.

I want to know, if there is a way to make emacsclient behave more like a lightweight GUI editor(e.g. vim) in this point?

Comment: I found the problem disappeared if I removed the "-n" option from the cmdline. That is, to start emacs daemon by using "emacsclient -c" instead of "emacsclient -c -n". I have created a script to handle the "return without waiting" stuff: http://pastebin.com/3vv1dSRB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking for trouble, but you you could try this:

```
(add-hook 'delete-frame-functions
          (lambda (frame)
            (let* ((window (frame-selected-window frame))
                   (buffer (and window (window-buffer window))))
              (when (and buffer (buffer-file-name buffer))
                (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use the command `quit-window` which does precisely what you want (with the prefix argument); it is already the binding for `q` in `special-mode` (i.e., not self-insert) buffers. You can bind it to, say, `C-f4`, and it will kill the buffer and the frame when you type `C-u C-f4`.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like the following:

```
(defun my-kill-buffer-and-frame ()
  "kill the current buffer and the current frame"
  (interactive)
  (when (y-or-n-p "Are you sure you wish to delete the current frame?")
    (kill-buffer)
    (delete-frame)))
```

If you're sure you always wnt to do it, you can get rid of the prompt:

```
(defun my-kill-buffer-and-frame ()
  "kill the current buffer and the current frame"
  (interactive)
  (kill-buffer)
  (delete-frame))
```

Then bind it to a key of your choice, like so:

```
(global-set-key [(f5)] 'my-kill-buffer-and-frame)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Cool! this is another possible solution :)